# How to retrieve the excel file data without Interop?

Tags: c#, .net, com-interop, excel-interop

Can anyone suggest me an approach to retrieve the excel file details (Alternative of Interop)?

I want to track user working excel file details (like workbook name, sheet name, formula present in the sheet/workbook, Macro value.)

Answer (score 0):

If the Excel file is an OpenXML file (XLSX or similar extensions), you could simply read it using [`Packaging`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in .NET. You have to extract all data yourself then, which is quite some work. You could use the [`DocumentFormat.OpenXml`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) to make reading a little easier.

Another option is to use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), which effectively does the same, but saves you a lot of work.

Comment: Hi , For EPPPlus we have to pass the filepath or memorystream of excel file then only we can retrieve the excel file data.Here In my application I am using Foregroundwindow API to capture the handle of active excel workbook and using handle ID  I would like to retrieve the excel data..

Comment: Can u suggest approach, by giving handle value to retrieve the excel file data....

Comment: As far as I know there are no tools to do so.

Comment: Other than Interop approach , do we have any methodology to capture excel data behind the screen without affecting running excel application.

Comment: @user3520395: Anything more I can do for you? If not, please accept the answer.

Comment: It does answer your question exactly.